# How to connect MySql localhost to reader when deploying project on RFID reader?

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

I am working on a project in which i have a MySql database stores in the local host. I want to connect to the localhost database when deploying application on RFID reader. I have written coding as

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;UserId=root;
                                                      database=**Database name**");
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM
                      login where Username = '" + textBox1.Text+ "' 
                      and Password = '" +textBox2.Text + "'", conn);

               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()== "1")
                {
                    MainMenuform ps = new MainMenuform();
                    ps.Show();
                    this.Hide();
               }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please check Username and Password");
                }
            }
```

So when i deploy the application, there are no build errors but when i put Username and password from the device and the getting an error message
"Can't connect to the MySqllocalhost" and points to

```
da.Fill(dt)
```

Do i need to specify something else like IP address of the local host. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: There's at least one type: you are missing space: `SELECT * FROM login`

Comment: Still giving me same error.